# How to return to a result page after file download?

Tags: java, struts2, download

I use Struts 2 to download a file from a JSP page. Everything works good, recording and file recovery is going well. Once I finish I must return a result page, but this page is distorted. If I call the page without downloading, it displays correctly. How can I return to a result page after file download?

I use Mozilla Firefox as browser, and Firebug tells me the following error:

> $ Is not defined

on the line `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Comment: Your question was confusing. I've edited it into a better shape. Please let me know if this is what you *really* are asking.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You only get one response per-request, so if you're downloading a file, that's it.

Comment: yes I download the file, but the result page i scompletly  distorted

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like you are missing a client-side JavaScript library, probably jQuery (or prototype, or MooTools etc.).