# struts 2 using ajax to upload a file

Tags: java, ajax, file-upload, struts2

I use struts 2, including ajax, to upload a file, everything works when downloading, I get the file, but the response page,returned by the action executed after uploading 
file, is completely distorted, it return an error in my base.js: ($. ajaxSetup ({is not defined)
Here the action called to save my file

```
public String saveFile() throws Exception { 
        if(uploadFileName!=null){
             String chemin=context.getRealPath("");
             File dirWebapps = new File(chemin);
             String fullFileName =myUrl+"/"+uploadFileName;
             File theFile = new File(dirWebapps.getParent(),fullFileName);
             FileUtils.copyFile(upload, theFile);
             URL repertoire = theFile.getParentFile().toURL();
            }
                 return "myPage";
         }
```

please,can someone help me

I define a bean in struts.xml file upload as follows:

and "myPage" contains

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%> <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/base.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){ ///something }) </script> <s:form id="courrierModel" validate="true" theme="simple" cssStyle="margin:0;padding:0px" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="GET"> some content </s:form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return to a result page after file download?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835088/how-to-return-to-a-result-page-after-file-download)

Comment: The answer is the same as the last time you asked :)

Comment: I try to say it with another way, because the answer did not help me

Comment: This code should be a file upload. Please include the contents of your struts.xml and the jsp to which you are pointing to in result name myPage.

Comment: @user1005045 Come on, put that in the question--how can we read that?

Comment: hhh sorry , I am new to this forum

Comment: As James said, do you mean upload, or download? The `saveFile` method appears to be upload code.

Answer (score 2):

All you got to do is return a http-header with status 200.

E.g. code :

```
<action name="uploadaction" class="actions.UploadAction">
   <result name="success" type="httpheader">
          <param name="status">200</param>
   </result>
</action>
```